# Permutations and Combinations of rows as per Id having SUM for dissimilar groups As a SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, permutation, combinations

I require a permutations and combinations of rows as per Id having SUM for dissimilar groups:
**As a SQL QUERY**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable2([Id] [int] NULL, [Group] [varchar](50) NULL, [PeriodStart] [varchar](50) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group1', 'date1a')<br/>
INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group1', 'date1b')<br/>
INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group1', 'date1c')<br/>
INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group2', 'date2a')<br/>
INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group2', 'date2b')<br/>
INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group3', 'date3a')<br/>
INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group3', 'date3b')<br/>
INSERT INTO TestTable2([Id], [Group], [PeriodStart]) VALUES (1, 'Group3', 'date3c')<br/>
```

Data in table:

```
**Id -- Group -- PeriodStart**<br/>
1 -- Group1 -- date1a<br/>
1 -- Group1 -- date1b<br/>
1 -- Group1 -- date1c<br/>
1 -- Group2 -- date2a<br/>
1 -- Group2 -- date2b<br/>
1 -- Group3 -- date3a<br/>
1 -- Group3 -- date3b<br/>
1 -- Group3 -- date3c<br/>
```

NOTE: There can be any number of Groups, PeriodStart is a DateTime

**OutPut required as: should be 18 combinations from 3*2*3 distinct group rows (i.e here for Group1, Group2 and Group3) with their MAX DATE of PeriodStart:**

```
**Id -- MaximumPeriodStartDate**<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1a, date2a, date3a)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1a, date2b, date3a)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1a, date2a, date3b)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1a, date2b, date3b)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1a, date2a, date3c)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1a, date2b, date3c)<br/>

1 -- MAX OF (date1b, date2a, date3a)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1b, date2b, date3a)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1b, date2a, date3b)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1b, date2b, date3b)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1b, date2a, date3c)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1b, date2b, date3c)<br/>

1 -- MAX OF (date1c, date2a, date3a)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1c, date2b, date3a)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1c, date2a, date3b)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1c, date2b, date3b)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1c, date2a, date3c)<br/>
1 -- MAX OF (date1c, date2b, date3c)<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6424/7).

```
SELECT SQ1.[ID]
        ,SQ1.[VALUE]+'+'+SQ2.[VALUE]+'+'+SQ3.[VALUE] AS COMBOS
FROM
(
SELECT [id],[VALUE]
FROM TESTTABLE2
WHERE [GROUP] = 1
) SQ1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT [id],[VALUE]
FROM TESTTABLE2
WHERE [GROUP] = 2
) SQ2
ON SQ1.[ID]= SQ2.[ID]
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT [id],[VALUE]
FROM TESTTABLE2
WHERE [GROUP] = 3
) SQ3
ON SQ1.[ID]= SQ3.[ID]
```

Comment: Thanks but in my case Groups are dynamic it can be any numbers of group against 1 ID and same group can occur any number of times here in my case Group (1) occurs 3 times and Group (2) occurs 2 times and so on.<br/>
I need something as SUM(Value), Count(Groups i.e number of groups included for this SUM).<br/>
NOTE: Same group should not occur twice while taking SUM of Value

Comment: Hi Declan I have updated my question also. I am sorry if i am not clear as I am new to posting Questions.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed your variables to things that are not reserved key words in most databases:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t1.ValStr+'+'+t2.ValStr+'+'+t3.ValStr
from @TestTable2 t1 join
     @TestTable2 t2
     on t1.TheGroup < t2.TheGroup  join
     @TestTable2 t3
     on  t2.TheGroup < t3.TheGroup
```

I'm using SQL Server syntax for the string concatenation, because it looks like you are using that database.

I cannot readily think of a way to handling any number of groups in a SQL-only query.  However, you can handle an "up-to" number of groups with something like:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id,
       stuff((coalesce('+'+t1.ValStr), '')+coalesce('+'+t2.ValStr, '') +
              coalesce('+'+t3.ValStr, '')+ . . .
             ), 1, 1, '')
from @TestTable2 t1 left outer join
     @TestTable2 t2
     on t1.TheGroup < t2.TheGroup left outer join
     @TestTable2 t3
     on  t2.TheGroup < t3.TheGroup . .
```

You would continue the left outer joins up to some maximum number of groups and fix the `select` clause accordingly.

The results are a bit different from what you want.  This produces all combinations of up to n groups, rather than exactly n groups.  So the first would produce:  (3 + 2 + 3) [combinations of 1] + (3 * 2 + 2 * 3 + 3 * 3) [combinations of 2] + (3 * 2 * 3).  You can fix this by using this rather cumbersome `where` clause:

```
where ((case when t1.thegroup is not null then 1 else 0 end)+
       (case when t2.thegroup is not null then 1 else 0 end)+
       (case when t3.thegroup is not null then 1 else 0 end)+
       . . .
      ) = (select count(distinct thegroup) from @TestTable2)
```

If your groups are numbered sequentially with no gaps, you can also write this as:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id,
       stuff((coalesce('+'+t1.ValStr), '')+coalesce('+'+t2.ValStr, '') +
              coalesce('+'+t3.ValStr, '')+ . . .
             ), 1, 1, '')
from @TestTable2 t1 left outer join
     @TestTable2 t2
     on t2.TheGroup = t1.TheGroup+1 left outer join
     @TestTable2 t3
     on t3.TheGroup = t2.TheGroup+1 . . .
where t1.TheGroup = 1
```

Actually, even if your groups are *not* numbered sequentially, you could arrange for this using `dense_rank()` and proceed from there:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by [Group]) as TheGroup
      from @TestTable2
     )
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id,
       stuff((coalesce('+'+t1.ValStr), '')+coalesce('+'+t2.ValStr, '') +
              coalesce('+'+t3.ValStr, '')+ . . .
             ), 1, 1, '')
from t t1 left outer join
     t t2
     on t2.TheGroup = t1.TheGroup+1 left outer join
     t t3
     on t3.TheGroup = t2.TheGroup+1 . . .
where t1.TheGroup = 1
```

The other approach is to use recursive CTEs.  Without that, this is probably the best SQL-only approach.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your reply, I am new in posting questions :-):
But in my case Groups are dynamic (**probably a string here i have take 1,2,3**) there can be any numbers of group.
For ID==1 and same group can occur any number of times here in my case Group (1) occurs 3 times and Group (2) occurs 2 times and so on.<br/>
I need something as SUM(Value), Count(Groups i.e number of groups included for this SUM).<br/>
NOTE: Same group should not occur twice while taking SUM of Value.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have updated my question also. I am sorry if i am not clear as I am new to posting Questions.